# How to get rid of items padding in a Sencha Touch List?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am using a sencha touch list. Sencha automatically adds a margin to every item. I don't want any horizontal or vertical margin or padding. How do I configure it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give itemCls to the list view like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'list',
    name: 'search_item_list',
    itemCls: 'search-item-list-item',
    store: 'PatientInfo',
    emptyText: 'No items found'
}
```

Now in the css file add this code:

```
.search-item-list-item .x-innerhtml{
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have clear idea on the Sencha components. If you don't want padding etc, go for Sencha "DataView". This will serve the purpose. But if you want to use "List" only, then you can do this trick in your css:

```
.x-list .x-list-item .x-list-item-label {
padding: 0em;
}
```

*This will remove padding from all list in your app. So be specific when using this.

Comment: I am actually using a dataview but it has an issue with the pullRefresh plugin : the pullRefresh visual effect is dragged faster than the dataview so it comes over it.